# How are TypeScript generics different from Java?

Tags: typescript, generics, type-parameter, structural-typing, nominal-typing

The following code would produce the expected type error in Java, but TypeScript doesn't consider it an error.  Is this by design, or is it a bug in TypeScript?

```
abstract class UnitType<T extends UnitType<T>> {
    ...
}

class Unit<T extends UnitType<T>> {
    ...
}

class Length extends UnitType<Length> {
    static meters: Unit<Length> = new Unit<Length>()
}
class Angle extends UnitType<Angle> {
    static degrees: Unit<Angle> = new Unit<Angle>()
}


class UnitizedNumber<T extends UnitType<T>> {
    constructor(value: number, unit: Unit<T>) {
        ...
    }
}

// Length and Angle are not compatible, so this should be an error.
const foo: UnitizedNumber<Length> = new UnitizedNumber<Length>(1, Angle.degrees)
```

In fact TypeScript doesn't even consider this an error:

```
const meters: Length = new Angle()
```

Does TypeScript treat all classes as structural instead of nominal types?  I'm used to Java and Flow treating classes as nominal types.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, my suspicion was correct, TypeScript currently treats classes as structural types but [more support for nominal types is planned](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/202).

According to https://michalzalecki.com/nominal-typing-in-typescript/ one way to force TypeScript to treat a class like a nominal type is to use a private property:

```
class Length extends UnitType<Length> {
    private __nominal: void
    static meters: Unit<Length> = new Unit<Length>()
}
class Angle extends UnitType<Angle> {
    private __nominal: void
    static degrees: Unit<Angle> = new Unit<Angle>()
}
```

However this still doesn't cause the desired errors above.  I had to make sure that the type parameter for `Unit` is actually used to cause an error:

```
class Unit<T extends UnitType<T>> {
    type: T
    constructor(type: T) {
        this.type = type
    }
}

const foo: UnitizedNumber<Length> = new UnitizedNumber<Length>(1, Angle.degrees)
```

> Argument of type 'Unit' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Unit'.
>     Type 'Angle' is not assignable to type 'Length'.
>       Types have separate declarations of a private property 'name'. (2345)